# Alternative for ON_COMMAND message map macro to call a function with a paramenter(s)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, afx

I've got a message map at the beginning of my program that looks like the following:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SoftwareDlg, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(SoftwareDlg)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_DESTROY()
    ...
    ON_COMMAND(ID_TOOLS_UPLOADDATA, UploadData)
    ...
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And here the function that the `ID_TOOLS_UPLOADDATA` menu option calls when clicked:

```
void UploadData()
{
    string apiEndpoint = "/api/stuff";
    upload_data(apiEndpoint);
}
```

My problem is that that I want my `UploadData()` function to be able to take the `string apiEndpoint` as a parameter so that I can call it from multiple locations in my program for multiple operations (not just when the user clicks the menu button). Like so:

```
void UploadData(string apiEndpoint = "/api/stuff")
{
    upload_data(apiEndpoint);
}
```

I took a look at [`ON_COMMAND_EX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=msvc-160#on_command_ex), but the [only usage example I was able to find](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?61254-q-the-difference-between-ON_COMMAND_EX-and-ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI&p=158547#post158547) does not appear to be what I'm looking for... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can't. There's no way for the system to pass any user-defined data through [WM_COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command). You're going to have to arrange to make the additional data accessible some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Iinspectable said, you can’t.
Try for example to add a member variable and set it before calling the function.

Comment: Ah, that helps. Still not quite what I was looking for, but I can make it work. Thanks.